Is there a C++ library that implements a circular buffer of dynamically sized arrays?
Moved from StackOverflow.
I need a queue of arrays, all of the same dimension but known only at run time. Think of it like a conveyor belt of one dimensional data vector, where I need to add and remove entire sequences of values at the front and the back. std::queue<std::vector<float>> would be good, but it allocates/deallocates space per each insertion/deletion of a new sequence. Boost has a circular buffer container, but the lenght of the single sequence, even though it is always the same, is not known at compile time, so I don't think I can use it. My Google fu hasn't find anything: are you aware of a C/C++ library, preferably FOSS that provides this thing? Or should I implement this from scratch using a bidimensional run time array?
